# Enable websocket connections

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl, websocket, port

I have a backend [www.backend.io](http://www.backend.io) with nodejs as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('flapper-news:server');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var port = normalizePort('3000');
app.set('port', port);

var fs = require("fs");
var config = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/key-new.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/cert-new.pem')
};

var server
if (process.env.httpORs === "http://") server = http.createServer(app);
else server = https.createServer(config, app)

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}

const WebSocket = require('websocket').server;
const wsServer = new WebSocket({ httpServer: server });
const { handleWebSocketUserMessage } = require('../routes/aiv4');
wsServer.on('request', (request) => {
  const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

  connection.on('message', (message) => {
      if (message.type === "utf8") {
          const data = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);

          if (data.type === 'userMessage') {
              handleWebSocketUserMessage(data.content, connection);
          }
      }
  });

  connection.on('close', (reasonCode, description) => {
      console.log(`Connection closed: ${reasonCode} - ${description}`);
  });
});
```

And the nginx configuration file is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name backend.io www.backend.io;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name backend.io www.backend.io;

    # use the following certificates with CloudFlare:
    # ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/certificate.pem;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/privatekey.pem;

    # use the following certificates without CloudFlare:
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.io/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location ~* ^/\b(?!pathSocketIO|1|js|socket.io|monaco-editor|libs|dist|fonts|javascripts|formatter|ui|css|stylesheets|htmls|imgs|static|httpOnly|tmp|uploads)\w+\b/? {
        rewrite .* /1/#$request_uri redirect;
    }

    location ~* ^/1/\b(?!#|auth)\w+\b/? {
        rewrite ^/1/(.*[.]js)$ https://www.backend.io/dist/$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/1/(.*[^.][^j][^s])$ https://www.backend.io/1/#/$1 redirect;
    }

    location = / {
        return 301 /home;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:3000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

In the frontend [www.frontend.io](http://www.frontend.io), I would like to establish a websocket by `new WebSocket("wss://www.backend.io");`, but it raises an error in the console of the frontned: `WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.backend.io/' failed:` .

I guess maybe it is because I'm using the port 3000 rather than 443 in the code. I tried to write `var port = normalizePort('443');` and launched the backend with `sudo`: `NODE_ENV=production sudo pm2 start npm -- start`, but the backend still raised an error: `Port 443 requires elevated privileges`.

Does anyone know how to set the port, modify the code or nginx to enable websocket connections?

Comment: You would need to proxy the connection through nginx to the websocket server. Websockets with Nginx is much easier using the nchan module, unless you have a specific reason to use your own Id recommend looking at it.